# Get List by "InternalName"

Tags: 2013, javascript, splist, client-object-model, properties

I'm trying to use the SharePoint 2013 JavaScript Object Model to retrieve a List via an internal name equivalent.

SPList doesn't have a `Name` or `Internal Name` property. It is referred to by the Title; however in my case the Title has been altered.

For example the current Title is 'My Images' however, the list URL is '/Lists/MyImages'

I've been browsing the SPList properties using **SharePoint Manager 2013** and I've found a couple of properties that might help:

- EntityTypeName ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.entitytypename(v=office.15).aspx))
- RootFolder ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.rootfolder(v=office.15).aspx))

Both of these properties are giving me the internal name ('MyImages') but I don't know anything about these properties and which property I should use (if either of them)

Can someone give me some info on these properties and what they are based on? The MSDN pages don't give me enough information to work with

Comment: why don't you access the list via GUID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use the GUID, you'll have to make an extra call and get the `vti_listname` property from the list folder. The folder you can get by url using the `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl` on the `SP.Web` object.

Example:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var web = clientContext.get_web();
var folder =  web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(String.format('{0}/lists/MyImages',_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl));

clientContext.load(folder, "Properties");

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    var list = web.get_lists().getById(folder.get_properties().get_item("vti_listname"));
    clientContext.load(list);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        console.log(list.get_title());

    },function(sender, args) {
        console.log("Fail: " + args.get_message());
    });

}, function(sender, args) {
    console.log("Fail: " + args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this code but the first `clientContext.executeQueryAsync` (loading `folder` properties) is giving me an exception - I enter the outer `fail` function

Comment: @jasonscript check if you are using the corret url: String.format('{0}/lists/MyImages',_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);

Answer (score 3):

Like to note that **RootFolder** as you point out yourself is not a bad idea if you were to use REST (and not jsom), like this:

```
/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=RootFolder/Name eq 'MyImages'
```

Then just pick the first one, and you get one result with all additional list data.
(Syntax tested on 365, might need `$expand` on-premise.)

Answer (score 1):

How to get List by its Url:

```
function getListByName(name,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var lists = ctx.get_web().get_lists();
   var result = ctx.loadQuery(lists, 'Include(RootFolder)');

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {
       var list;  
       for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
           if(result[i].get_rootFolder().get_name() == name) {
               list = result[i];
               break;
           } 
       }
       success(list);
      }, 
      error);
}
```

Key points:

- requires only a single request to the server
- compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013 JSOM

**Usage**

```
getListByName('Pages',
    function(list) {
        if(list) 
            console.log('List has been found');
    },
    function(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
```

Comment: Great! But, I'm still curious about the property EntityTypeName, is it a safe way to rely on while getting a list?

Comment: Be aware that you will need extra permissions to get rootfolder of lists, that's why personally i prefer Anders Aune's solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use Getlist method of the Web object [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getlist.aspx).